# Ajax returns undefined on console.log(errors) - php server side validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

I want the user to be notified when there is a validation error from php. i am using laravel 5.3 to create the form and Ajax to get the error message.

here is my JavaScript code

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/artistPost',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        _token: Artisttoken,
        Name: Name,
        Phone: Phone,
    },

     error:function (data, response, xhr, status, error) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log(errors);
    }
```

this is what i am seeing in the Network section of the Chrome deveper tools

```
<?php{"name":["The name field is required."],"phone":["The phone field is required."]}
```

and this is what I am seeing in the console[image]

Update

this is from the controller

```
 public function create(ArtistRequest $request){

    dd($request->all());


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Is that all of your php code for artistPost? or is it the output?

Comment: its the output when I click on Save

Comment: Can we see the code that produces that output?

Comment: the "/artistpost" url invokes the "create()" function which i have updated in my question

Comment: show the code of ArtistRequest

Answer (score 1):

Your server should not be sending `<?php` as part of it's response - this either suggests that the server is not parsing the file as PHP, or you are echoing a `<?php` tag somehow.

This post seems to be addressing a very similar issue:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/php-tag-in-ajax-response?page=1

Look in particular at this response:

> RouteServiceProvider.php contains:
>
> `public function map(Router $router)
>      {
>          $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router)
>          {
>              foreach (File::allFiles(app_path('Http/Routes')) as $partial)
>              {
>                  require_once($partial->getPathname());
>              }
>          });
>      }`
>
> One of the route files loaded by the above method currently has nothing in it except for a `<?php` tag and **NO NEW LINE**. The absence of a new line was the problem. Added a comment to the file and all works perfectly. I don't know why this was more of a problem on the production server than locally. The PHP versions are both 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to return a json output from the controller. Eg:

```
    return Response::json(['message'=> 'Your message', 'status'=> 'success'], 200);
```

You should have an if/else so you can capture success and error.